# Enable more ports to public traffic on AWS? Nginx/Docker multiple applications setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I currently have an EC2 instance running over on AWs, with two applications (a frontend app and an API, standard stuff)

By default I have port 80 and 443 enabled for public traffic, by my company's devops team.

Im trying to use Nginx, to redirect requests incoming to port :80, to different app/api ports setup on docker containers.

example: my app is currently running on port `:8080`, I expect that when user hits my domain, nginx redirects user to the app running on `:8080`

nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name company.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
        }    
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name company.locallabs.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/wildcard.company.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/wildcard.company.com.key;
        
        location /api {
            rewrite /api/(.*) /$1         break;
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081;
        }
    }
}
```

Question: port `:8080` is accessible only within the server (when I access using SSH, and run a CURL inside the server it works fine).

**Should `:8080` be enabled to public traffic, even though I set the redirect on Nginx**?

nginx logs gives me

```
2021/04/14 04:01:07 [error] 6#6: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 3.90.2.223, server: company.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "company.com"
```

Comment: Instead of using "0.0.0.0:<PortNo>", use container Ip address.
To get container IP address- docker inspect <Container_Name>

Comment: thanks for your time @karansharma, tried and replaced it, but still got the same error 111: Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't.

I recommend that you consider deploying the docker container [jc21/nginx-proxy-manager](https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager).  It works beautifully and has the added benefit that it manages LetsEncrypt SSL certs for each service it proxies.

Have the nginx container ingest host ports 80 and 443, and use the UI to define the domains and ports for each docker container your devs are working on.